# Why Java’s exception-handling statements should not be considered a general mechanism for nonlocal branching?

Tags: java, exception

Going through Herbert Schildt : The Complete Reference Chapter 10 Exception Handling

> Exception handling provides a powerful mechanism for controlling complex programs that
> have many dynamic run-time characteristics. It is important to think of try, throw, and catch
> as clean ways to handle errors and unusual boundary conditions in your program’s logic.
> Unlike some other languages in which error return codes are used to indicate failure, Java
> uses exceptions. Thus, when a method can fail, have it throw an exception. This is a cleaner
> way to handle failure modes.
> One last point: Java’s exception-handling statements should not be considered a general
> mechanism for nonlocal branching. If you do so, it will only confuse your code and make it
> hard to maintain.

What does he mean by the term 'nonlocal branching'?

Comment: For example using a NumberFormatException to test if input from a user is numeric.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the computational complexity of setting up for and catching an exception vs. more conventional flow control.  But I can't elaborate, which is why this is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: I think "Java’s exception-handling statements should not be considered a general mechanism for nonlocal branching" means using the exception bubbling mechanism to branch to some other function by calling the other function in the `catch` block way up the call stack(similar to using `goto` statement to branch non locally). This breaks the conventional control flow and makes the logic difficult to understand and maintain.

Comment: He means not using it as a `goto`. However as several generations of programmers have now been born who have never heard of a `goto` the warning is considerably out of date. They used to also say "don't use exceptions as a form of flow control": the problem with that statement being that exceptions *are* a form of flow control. Just use them for errors and you won't get hurt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example of a local branch:

```
void foo() {
  if (someCondition) {
    doSomething();
  } else {
    doSomethingElse();
  }
}
```

The branching is quite forward to understand, right? The reason for this simplicity is that all branching logic is defined within `foo`. Locally, so to speak. This means, a condition is checked and its path is taken depending on `someCondition` but the branching does not escape `foo`. By only looking at this one method, you know how the code flow might look like.

Now think of this less-readable implementation:

```
void foo() {
  if(bar()) {
    // branch is handled by bar
  } else {
    doSomethingElse();
  }
}

boolean bar() {
  if(somethingWrong) {
    return false;
  }
  doSomething();
}
```

This is less readable. But why is that? If you are calling a method `bar` from `foo`, the control flow is handled by `bar`. `bar` might however do something unexpected and still rely on `foo` to handle this unexpected condition. This is not a good practice as you distribute connected logic among `foo` and `bar` where a change at one place might cause a misbehavior at another place. This is somewhat what exceptions do if they are treated *too far down the stack*. You can even extend the complexity of the above example by adding more intermediate methods. Therefore, the book suggests, to keep branching locally as this often is more human readable and traceable what I would equally suggest as a good idea. Look at this exception-based implementation of the above code to visualize this more:

```
void foo() {
  try {
    bar()
  } catch(SomeException e) {
    doSomethingElse();
  }
}

boolean bar() {
  if(somethingWrong) {
    throw new SomeException();
  }
  doSomething();
}
```

Obviously, this distributed branch is more error-prone than an `if`-`else` statement.

Comment: the answer on the coderanch seems to suggest the same thing. Are you sure this is what Herbert Schildt referred to as nonlocal branching? or is there more to this. I am just guessing at what would ever compel me to have the second version(less readable one above) in my program?

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari When the processing in the branch is complicated enough that it needs its own method or even class. In fact, the Replace Conditional with Polymorphism refactoring eliminates `if` statements entirely and requires separate classes for different behaviors.

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari Yes, I am pretty sure this is what is meant. Non-local branching always considers a branch that is distributed among methods. In Java, this is only possible via exceptions.